# vue.js v-if fails in combination with drag drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, vue.js

I am working on a dragdrop mechanism and need the items updated with the right column id after drop. This works until I drop the item back into the original element. Then it disappears. Looking at the data object, the correct data is shown

https://jsfiddle.net/rooseboom/u6u23u1o/

move the grey Test3 card from Backlog to Todo. You see the board id data is updated (like it should). Now move it back again. In the top data shown, the board id is again correctly updated but the item disappears (v-if statement as far as I can tell)

I can't figure out why the item disappears. Any help? thx.

html:

```
<div id="boardcanvas" class="boardcanvas">

        <div v-for="(task, index) in tasks" >
                       data: {{task.name}} - boardid: {{task.boardId}} <br>
        </div>
        <Br><br>

        <div v-for="(column,index) in columns" v-bind:id="'column'+column.boardId" class="boardcolumn">

            <div class="columnHeader"> {{ column.boardName }}</div>

            <div class="columnContent" v-bind:id="column.boardId">

                <div v-for="(task, index) in tasks" v-if="task.boardId == column.boardId" v-bind:id="task.taskId+'-'+index" class="cardcontainer">
                    <span class="card">
                        {{task.name}} <br> {{task.boardId}}
                    </span>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

javascript:

```
var boards = JSON.parse("[{\"boardId\":\"1234567894\",\"boardName\":\"Backlog\"},{\"boardId\":\"1234567890\",\"boardName\":\"Todo\"},{\"boardId\":\"1234567893\",\"boardName\":\"Done\"}]");

var tasksd = JSON.parse("[{\"taskId\":\"58646f066803fa62388b4573\",\"name\":\"test1\",\"boardId\":\"1234567891\"},{\"taskId\":\"58646f066803fa62388b4572\",\"name\":\"test2\",\"boardId\":\"1234567894\"},{\"taskId\":\"58646f066803fa62388b4571\",\"name\":\"test3\",\"boardId\":\"1234567894\"}]");

var appBoard = new Vue({
  el:'#boardcanvas',
  data: {
    columns: boards,
    columnCount: boards.length,
    tasks: tasksd,
  },
  mounted: function(){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.tasks))
    $( ".columnContent" ).sortable({
      revert: true,
      opacity: 0.5,
      helper: 'clone',
      placeholder: 'drag-place-holder',
      forcePlaceholderSize: true,a
      connectWith: ".columnContent",
      start: function (e, ui) {ui.item.show().addClass('ghost')},
      stop: function (e, ui) {
        ui.item.show().removeClass('ghost')
      },
      update: function(e, ui) {
        if(ui.sender){
          var newBoardId = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');

          var currentTaskId = ui.item.attr('id')
          var taskSplit = currentTaskId.split("-");
          var taskIndex = parseInt(taskSplit[1])

          appBoard.moveTask(taskIndex,newBoardId)
        }
      },
      cursor:'move'
    })
  },
  methods:{
    moveTask: function(index,newBoardId) {

      appBoard.$set(this.tasks[index], 'boardId', newBoardId)

      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.tasks))
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I'm going to delete the answer below soon if it wasn't helpful.